# DescriptionBox that stays open when mouse is over description

Tags: javascript, mouseover, jquery-hover

I am currently attempting to have my description box visible when a mouse over the description box and disappears when the mouse isn't in the description box.

```js
function hidebox(nodeId){
            document.getElementById(nodeId).style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    function showbox(nodeId){
        document.getElementById(nodeId).style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```css
 span.descriptionDisplay {
      display:none;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 15px 0 0 0;
        width: 780px;
        z-index: 999;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f2f2eb;
        color: #222;
        font-size: 19px;
        line-height: 24px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.3);
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
    
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" onmouseover="showbox('description')" onmouseout="hidebox('description')" onclick="return false;"> <sup>Help me stay open on hover </sup></a><span id="description" class="descriptionDisplay">See Jean E. Howard, The Stage and Social Struggle in Early Modern England (London: Routledge, 1994); Christopher Warley, Sonnet Sequences and Social Distinction in Renaissance England (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2005); Christopher Warley, Reading Class Through Shakespeare, Donne, and Milton (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2014).</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS not needed. You can do this with pure CSS.

The key element I changed was creating a container element around everything, and changing the margin-top to a padding-top on a container for the description.

The reason your example was failing was because there was a margin space between the hover and the description, which means it wasn't actually over the element so it couldn't show the description.

```
.container:hover .description {
  display: block;
}

.description-container {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Demo here
https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoxey/fsnt0t6v/